# Session enable in retrofit for woocommerce api

Tags: android, wordpress, session, woocommerce, retrofit

I am working on a project where I am using woocommerce API to add items to cart.Add to cart is working fine but when I kill the app from the background and reopen the app woocommerce API could not able to fetch the data using session key.

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
CookieHandler cookieHandler = new CookieManager();
PersistentCookieStore cookieStore = new PersistentCookieStore(MuraliFlutesApplication.getInstance());
CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager(cookieStore, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ORIGINAL_SERVER);
cookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
httpClient.readTimeout(120, TimeUnit.HOURS).connectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.HOURS).addNetworkInterceptor(logging).cookieJar(new JavaNetCookieJar(cookieHandler));
httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);
```

Comment: Please share some code of your project, you can check more about it here:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            CookieHandler cookieHandler = new CookieManager();
            PersistentCookieStore cookieStore = new PersistentCookieStore(MuraliFlutesApplication.getInstance());
            CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager(cookieStore, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ORIGINAL_SERVER);
            cookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

Comment: OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
            httpClient .readTimeout(120, TimeUnit.HOURS)
                    .connectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.HOURS)
                    .addNetworkInterceptor(logging)
                    .cookieJar(new JavaNetCookieJar(cookieHandler));
            httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);